# Blazor Wasm App with Entity Framework works on desktop but not as Azure Static Website

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor-webassembly

Problem occurs in deployed version when the client actions any database action via the  server controller but not on desktop:

I get a 500 Server Error.  It seems that the problem is SQL Server database access issue.
I'm using an Azure Sql Server both on desktop (with IIS Express) and when deployed. Same connection string.

I have viewed similar issues here and solutions but haven't found one that works.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: net_http_message_not_success_statuscode, 500, Internal Server Error
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: net_http_message_not_success_statuscode, 500, Internal Server Error
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.<GetFromJsonAsyncCore>d__9`1[[EFBlazorBasics_Wasm.Shared.Activity[], EFBlazorBasics_Wasm.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()
   at EFBlazorBasics_Wasm.Client.Pages.FetchDbDataDirect.OnInitializedAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)
```

Comment: How is the application authorized to access the Azure Sql Database? Is it username / password, RBAC, Managed Identity?

Comment: SQL DB Username and Password in the Connection string in appsettings.json in the server.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that in configuring the app for deployment I had configured it to use another database on the same Azure SQL Server on the Publish panel in Visual Studio, thus overriding the appsettings.json setting for the connection string.

I should have noticed what db was being used on left under Service Dependencies. Instead I recorded the connection string as a static string in Startup class in ConfigureServices() and passed that back to the client as the content of a Get Ok for display.

Comment: Nice catch! This is helpful info, because the Publish settings to tend to 'hide' some things if you don't know where to look for them.